# How to send String data to wit.ai using OkHttp

Tags: java, android, httprequest, okhttp

I'm currently working with wit.ai api to try and make a chat ai,but it is my first time using an api and I don't know how to sent or receive data to the api. Can anyone pls help me with this.

Here is my current code:

```
MediaType medType = MediaType.parse("text/plain; charset=utf-8");
            
            httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    httpBuilder = HttpUrl.parse("https://api.wit.ai/message").newBuilder();

    httpBuilder.addQueryParameter("v", "20230618");
    httpRequest = new Request.Builder()
        .url(httpBuilder.build())
        .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN)
            .post(RequestBody.create(medType,"I'm Pat"))
        .header("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked")
        .build();
      
      try{
          Response response = httpClient.newCall(httpRequest).execute();
                ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
                
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    
                
                                                                  @Override
                                                                  public void run() {
                            try{
                                mytxtView.setText(responseBody.string());
                            }catch(IOException e){
                                mytxtView.setText("IOException");
                            }
                                                                  }
                                                                  
});
      }catch(IOException e){
          
      }
```

The code above returns unsupported post request.

Update:

I have change my Request.Builder to this:

```
httpRequest =
      new Request.Builder()
          .url(httpBuilder.build())
          .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN)
          .header("Content-Type","text/plain")
          .get()
          .build();
```

It works! I don't get the unsupported request error anymore.The problem is I don't know where to put the string data that I want to send.

Comment: First, you should at least log the stack trace in the catch block and edit and post the outcome into your question.

Comment: Seems that https://wit.ai/docs is down right now. Probably, you are not using the right HTTP method for this endpoint.

Comment: The catch block is not executed though

Comment: At `https://wit.ai/docs/http/20230215/` is no POST /message endpoint documented.